# WCF XmlSerializerFormat not receiving the request body

Tags: c#, android, wcf

```
 [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetBulkQueryUpdates", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        XmlDocument GetBulkQueryUpdates(string FTID, string UUID, string TYPE, string DateTimeStamp, string SDFVersionNb);
```

i have this WCF web methods which returns XmlDocument. i searched and found that i have to add XmlSerializerFormat to the operation contract which i did. 
the problem is when i am calling this web method from the android application, the web method is not receiving any of the attributes sent.

here is how i am sending the attributes:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(URL)).openConnection();
 conn.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
....
 OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
....
```

PS: i am new to WCF web services. Also, other web methods are woking normally but they return a string and i am  not adding XmlSerializerFormat to it.

Comment: First why you use POST method ? Better idea will be use GET.  What platform of Android are you use, is it Xamarin?  When you call this wcf other way what you get? Show it.

Comment: i am using POST for no specific reason but the android code is already implemented and was using an ASMX web service. also why not POST...

Comment: when i call using GET from the browser it is working fine but i dont want to use GET

Comment: For Android are you use xaamrin?

Comment: No i am using native

Comment: `XmlDocument` is object of .Net Framework, if you're consuming this service from an Android client, you should return the `XmlDocument` as a string.

Comment: ok thanks i will try that. but it used to work fine in an asmx service.

Comment: If you can use JSON instead XmlDocument, try it. JSON is recommended for mobile apps.

Comment: You're using post for no reason but don't want to use get? Why?

Comment: it's not for no reason at all. sometimes the data sent is pretty huge and also as i said i am not developing a new application. this is an old application and i am just updating the web service from asmx to wcf